# front-end Vue.js app in Kubernetes docker container cannot connect to back-end

Tags: docker, vue.js, kubernetes, axios

I have built a front-end Vue.js application, running on a docker container under kubernetes environment. the backend is also in the same kubernetes cluster (I am using Minikube for the project). When running it gets error `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` when connecting to back-end containers:
[image]

while inside the container, there is no problem connect to the back-end using curl:

```
$ kubectl exec -it deployment/hpl-browser-deployment -- sh
/ # curl http://hpl-manager-service:2354
{
  "message": "Manager status", 
  "state": "IDLE"
}
```

I used `axios` for the api service:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class APIService {
  API_URL = '';

  constructor(apiAddress) {
    this.API_URL = apiAddress;
  }

  async get() {
    console.log('ApiService: get()');
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(this.API_URL);
      console.log(`ApiService: get result: ${response.data}`);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return error;
    }
  }

  async postPlainText(data) {
    console.log(`ApiService: post() - data: ${data}`);
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(this.API_URL,
        data,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            Accept: '*/*',
          },
        });
      console.log(`ApiService: post result: ${response.data}`);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return error;
    }
  }
}
```

The application has no problem running on development environment, when I port-forward the back-end service, and connect to `http://localhost:2354`.

I would like to know what may cause this problem?

Comment: The frontend is only hosted in the container, but is running from the browser in the client. Your backend will also need to be accessible from the browser on the client for it to work.

Comment: Thanks @jbud, can you elaborate more? Isn't it the browser client connecting to front-end in the container, and then the front-end sending API commands and getting responses to/from the back-end, so the communication should be happening only between the front-end and the back-end inside the same kubernetes cluster (I have added some more details about my setup, so I am using Minikube, the front-end and back-end containers are running on the same kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Your frontend and backend could run on separate clusters, it wouldn’t matter. The client in this case is the user’s browser. The frontend is just being hosted in the container, the client is downloading it to their workstation, so the API(backend) needs to be accessible to user’s browser. It doesn’t really matter that the container hosting the frontend can communicate with backend. If you were running server side scripts then it would matter. Now your actually only running client side script.

Comment: The communication between frontend and backend doesn’t go through the container of the frontend, but directly from the client to the backend.

Comment: I see what you mean, so in that case, I will need to expose my backend and then store the IP address in front-end, so that the client can connect to the backend service? But I remember most of the applications only need to expose the front-end IP address?

Comment: Normally for the backend you would use something like an API gateway which will expose a url to connect to all the backend services.

Comment: Your backend in this case functions as an API for your frontend, which also needs to be accessible from the public viewing end

Comment: In kubernetes for each deployment you need to have service. So for backend you need to configure deployment and service. Then in vue deployment you can connect to your backend by service name.

Comment: Here is my example app helm charts (templates for kubernetes deployment) to have configuration like yours. https://gitlab.com/gintsgints/vue-fullstack/-/tree/master/helm/templates

Comment: @GintsGints, I did have deployment and service of the backend up running, and I can curl the service from inside the frontend deployment container (please check the question which I have updated)

Comment: @jbud, I think you are correct, thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @jbud Great explaination, I’d really appreciate it if you could post it as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your front-end vue.js application is just hosted in the container. The application is actually run from the browser of the client. Your backend which functions as the API will also need to be accessible to the browser of the client. The communication between frontend and backend doesn’t go through the container of the frontend, but directly from the client to the backend.

The connection between the front-end container and backend container is not used/needed in this case since you're not rendering anything from the front-end container, before responding to the client. If you were using a server-side rendering technology, such as PHP, Django, .net, Nodejs, etc., whereby you needed to connect to the backend to get some data and render something before replying to the client, then the connection between the front-end container and the backend container would be relevant.

Your current setup is no different from hosting your application/code on a CDN and accessing the API hosted on a separate service(publicly available).